# Converting a list of structs to a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a list of struct, with each struct having two short values and a byte value.  I would like to write this to a HEX file just containing the raw data.  This HEX value will get loaded onto a microcontroller.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to dump these values into a file.?

Comment: Can you provide details, such as how you want a short or a byte value formatted?  Any spaces between the hex values?  What kind of list of what kind of structs?

Comment: I don't care how the short is formatted, so long as I know what the format is

Comment: Is the list of structs the whole content of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by a hex file you actually mean a binary file, not a text file with hex codes.

The structure will have padding in it, so you can't just dump the list straight into a file.

Just get the values from each struct and write to the file using a BinaryWriter:

```
using (FileStream file = File.OpenWrite("FileName.ext")) {
  using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(file)) {
    foreach (Data data in theList) {
      writer.Write(data.FirstShort);
      writer.Write(data.SecondShort);
      writer.Write(data.TheByte);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your struct is

```
struct Package {
    public short First { get; private set; }
    public short Second { get; private set; }
    public byte Third { get; private set; }
    public Package(short first, short second, byte third) : this() {
        this.First = first;
        this.Second = second; 
        this.Third = third;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
void WritePackageOnWriter(Package package, BinaryWriter binaryWriter) {
    binaryWriter.Write(package.First);
    binaryWriter.Write(package.Second);
    binaryWriter.Write(package.Third);
}
```

So that

```
// binaryWriter is BinaryWriter
// packages is IEnumerable<Package>
foreach(var package in packages) {
    WritePackageOnWriter(package, binaryWriter);
}
```

If necessary, you can reconstitute via

```
Package ReadPackageFromReader(BinaryReader binaryReader) {
    short first = binaryReader.ReadInt16();
    short second = binaryReader.ReadInt16();
    byte third = binaryReader.ReadByte();
    return new Package(first, second, third);
}
```

Comment: Roughly what I was writing but expressed better.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this site: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/

I think you will want more control over your data types especially with Serialize/Deserializing your data. This will allow you to control EXACTLY how you marshall your datatypes.

Taken Directly from Mastering Structs in C#

**Struct Layout**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,
Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE
{
    public int cb;
    [MarshalAs(
        UnmanagedType.ByValArray,
        SizeConst=32)]
        public char[] DeviceName;
    [MarshalAs(
        UnmanagedType.ByValArray,
        SizeConst=128)]
        public char[] DeviceString;
    public int StateFlags;
    [MarshalAs(
        UnmanagedType.ByValArray,
        SizeConst = 128)]
        public char[] DeviceID;
    [MarshalAs(
        UnmanagedType.ByValArray,
        SizeConst = 128)]
        public char[] DeviceKey;
}
```

**Serialization**

```
public static byte[]
    RawSerialize(object anything)
{
    int rawsize =
        Marshal.SizeOf(anything);
    IntPtr buffer =
        Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawsize);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(anything,
        buffer, false);
    byte[] rawdata = new byte[rawsize];
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, rawdata,
        0, rawsize);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
    return rawdata;
}
```

Side note:

For basic serialization I would not try to roll my own I would just use built in .NET serialization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0.aspx